# Set Theory (Definition of a set)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A set is defined as the collection of well-defined and distinct objects. This implies that a member of a set can't be repetitive in the set. Now when we discuss groups in Group Theory, if we check the closure of the set Z of integers on which addition is the binary operation then for example we also check that since 2 belongs to Z so 2+2=4 and hence 4 also belongs to Z but we took 2 twice from the set this implies that there were more than one 2's in the set. I am confused that isn't it a repetition? Please I need a reliable and satisfactory answer.

Comment: First we chose an element $x$ from the set $\Bbb Z$. Then we chose an element $y$ from the set $\Bbb Z$. It might or might not be the case that $x$ happens to be the *same* element as $y$.

Comment: The addition  that you speak of must be seen as a function $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb Z$. There is only *one* pair $\langle 2,2\rangle$ in $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$

Comment: Yes I know that but I am confused in the case when x becomes equal to y.

Comment: In any (additive) group, for any element $g$, the sum $g+g$ with itself must also be defined.

Answer (score 6):

The set $\mathbb Z$ contains only one element $2$.

That does not mean that $2$ cannot be added to itself, however. The **group** $\mathbb Z$ is actually a tuple $(\mathbb Z, +)$, where $+$ is a binary operation on $\mathbb Z$.

Strictly speaking, $+$ is a mapping from $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$, and this mapping maps the **pair** $(2,2)$ to the **number** $4$. In a sense, there is no repetition because the operation $+$ works on the set in which there is only one **pair** of numbers that equals $(2,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

> we also check that since 2 belongs to Z so 2+2=4 and hence 4 also
>   belongs to Z but we took 2 twice from the set this implies that there
>   were more than one 2's in the set

You do not exhaust a set by using one of its elements as an argument for a function. The set stays the same. It acts as description of all feasible argument choices. Different arguments are treated independently.

Applying $2$ to the first argument, we get a function $+(2,.): \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, the function which increases its argument by two, and applying $2$ to the second argument we get the number $4$ as result:
$$
2+2 = +(2,2) = (+(2,.))(2) = 4
$$
The repetition of "taking" $2$ from the set $\mathbb{Z}$ does not matter, as the set does not change.